# Azure DevOps Server Pie chart slice not filtering

Tags: pie-chart, dashboard, azure-devops-server

I have a Pie chart as follows:

[image: Open User Stories by State]

It has slices representing count of `Work Items` by `State`. When I click a slice, I'm taken tot he query result showing all work items instead of filtered to clicked state:

[image: Results]

Here is the query:

[image: Query Editor]

What do I have to change here to get a filtered result instead of all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the "Filter work item" option in the top right corner to filter the status of work items.**

[image]

[image]

As of this time, however, clicking on a slice and then displaying work items of that status is not supported. When you click on the chart, you essentially open the query used by the chart.

So you need to manually filter your desired status after clicking. In addition to status, it also supports filtering of information such as Assigned to, Tags, and so on.